# MongoDB query to find property of first element of array

Tags: mongodb

I have the following data in MongoDB (simplified for what is necessary to my question).

```
{
    _id: 0,
    actions: [
        {
            type: "insert",
            data: "abc, quite possibly very very large"
        }
    ]
}
{
    _id: 1,
    actions: [
        {
            type: "update",
            data: "def"
        },{
            type: "delete",
            data: "ghi"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like is to find the first action type for each document, e.g.

```
{_id:0, first_action_type:"insert"}
{_id:1, first_action_type:"update"}
```

(It's fine if the data structured differently, but I need those values present, somehow.)

EDIT: I've tried `db.collection.find({}, {'actions.action_type':1})`, but obviously that returns *all* elements of the actions array.

NoSQL is quite new to me. Before, I would have stored all this in two tables in a relational database and done something like `SELECT id, (SELECT type FROM action WHERE document_id = d.id ORDER BY seq LIMIT 1) action_type FROM document d`.

Comment: simply `...actions[0] ` for `collection.find method`

Comment: These documents are large...I looking to use a projection or something to help me get only what I need.

Comment: you could add indexes

Comment: In a SO question like this, you should include an attempted solution, in this case a query you have tried, which did not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/slice/) operator in projection. (but for what you do i am not sure that the order of the array remain the same when you update it. Just to keep in mind))

```
db.collection.find({},{'actions':{$slice:1},'actions.type':1})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `$arrayElemAt` operator is actually the most elegant way, although the syntax may be unintuitive:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: {first_action_type: {$arrayElemAt: ["$actions.type", 0]}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Aggregation Pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) introduced in version 2.2:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$actions' },
  { $group: { _id: "$_id", first_action_type: { $first: "$actions.type" } } }
])
```

Comment: It will give back the whole array, there is a need for an unwind before the group. like this:  db.collection.aggregate([   { $unwind: '$actions' },   { $group: { _id: "$_id", first_action_type: { $first: "$actions.type"} } } ])

Comment: @PaulDraper Sorry had a typo. Fixed, you can try now :)